# tailwindcss не генерирует стили

Tags: css, tailwindcss, tailwind

Установил `tailwindcss`, подключил все нужные стили у себя в файле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю команду для генерации конечного файла со стилями:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в конечном итоге получаю файл на 400 строк, хотя их должно быть десятки тысяч:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так?

Comment: как-то решили проблему?

Comment: @Che они генерируются на лету то есть только те которые ты реально юзаешь, вроде как это нововведение в 3 тейлвинд

Answer (score 1):

Потому что при Вашей команде, компилируются только те классы которые есть в вашем проекте. То есть что бы в Вашем фаиле public/styles.css были десятки тысяч строк, содержащих весь набор классов tailwind - надо и задействовать все эти классы в вашем проекте!

Comment: я решил, что лучше поздно чем ни когда! Вдруг кому то пригодиться